# Is there a method which find the element by X, and then return Y?

Tags: javascript

Is there a method which find the element by *X*, and then return *Y* ?

For example:

```
[{id: 0, name: "bob"}
,{id: 1, name: "alice"}
,{id: 2, name: "john"}
].find_xxx((v) => v.id == 1 && v.name);
# => "alice"
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should be enough to do this.

Comment: filter() and map() both run through an array whether if found or not

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method which returns the element based on the test function and later get name property from the returned object.

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "bob"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "alice"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "john"
}].find(v => v.id == 1);

console.log(
  obj && obj.name
)
```

Comment: What happens if more than one Object is found, or no Objects are found; I'd assume there's an error condition?

Comment: @DavidThomas :  in case more than one it return the first... if no elements are found returns `undefined`

Comment: @DavidThomas :  so check the returned value

Comment: or `([{
  id: 0,
  name: "bob"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "alice"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "john"
}].find(v => v.id == 1) || {}).name`

Comment: this is what i was looking for!